# Comparing 2 lists with ref to position of element?

Tags: python, list, compare

I have 2 lists

```
question = [a, b, c, d] 
solution = [c, b, c, a]
```

so I have  to compare each individual element according to position and return the results (correct or wrong and state the correct answer)

so question 1 answer = a but the solution = c so output should print Q 1: a, wrong answer is c

How do I write a function which will display that output?

Comment: Well, this sounds like a simple loop problem. Have you tried anything? Maybe iterating through one of the lists, and checking the corresponding element on the other?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
question = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
solution = ['c', 'b', 'c', 'a']

results = [x == y for x, y in zip(question, solution)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> results
[False, True, True, False]
```

Or, for descriptive strings, we can add [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
results = [f"Q{i}: {a[0]}, wrong answer is {a[1]}" if a[0] != a[1] else f"Q{i}: {a[0]} - correct" for i, a in enumerate(zip(question, solution), 1)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> results
['Q1: a, wrong answer is c',
 'Q2: b - correct',
 'Q3: c - correct',
 'Q4: d, wrong answer is a']
```

Comment: `enumerate(zip(question, solution), 1)`, you can specify the start for enumerate

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to "glue" the right/wrong answer, and `enumerate` to track the number of the question.

```
question = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
solution = ['c', 'b', 'c', 'a']

for ix, (q, s), in enumerate(zip(question, solution), 1):
    if q != s:
        print(f'Q{ix} is wrong, answer was {q} but solution was {s}!')
```

```
Q1 is wrong, answer was a but solution was c!
Q4 is wrong, answer was d but solution was a!
```